# Is there a way to have two divs side by side in an li tag?

Tags: html, scroll, html-lists, css-float

I have a list that is scrolling using jquery. I want to have two separate divs inside the li so they scroll together, but one is hidden unless called by a function.
**EG:**

```
<ul id="scrollul">
  <li id="item1" class="active">
     <div>1</div>
     <div style="display:none;">2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: dear please provide the full code/fiddle so we can see what exactly you want to achieve and we can help you asap.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnZuY/)

I want another box to pop out when you click each item. I can work out the jquery needed just need to get the html sorted to have boxes next to the existing items

Comment: See the updated fiddle with two div aligned side by side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the updated fiddle with two div aligned side by side

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnZuY/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnZuY/1/embedded/result/

Note: i just put the border for boundaries so you can identify the elements easily. I removed display:none; from #right div temporary, so you can see the #right div in demo. PLease put it back as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may want to nest the 2nd div tag inside of the 1st div tag so that the 2nd div content has the 1st div tag content as it's container, like below:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="scrollul">
   <li id="item1" class="active">
      <div id="div1"> 1st content
         <div id="div2">2nd content</div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#item1{
    list-style:none;
}

#div1{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}

#div2{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    display: none;
}
```

If this isn't the case, I think you will need to better define your question.